# JavaScript identify whether this is a valid JS class or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to convert React.js project to a next.js project.

I have this **udf-compatible-datafeed.js** file

```js
import * as tslib_1 from "tslib";
import { UDFCompatibleDatafeedBase } from "./udf-compatible-datafeed-base";
import { QuotesProvider } from "./quotes-provider";
import { Requester } from "./requester";
var UDFCompatibleDatafeed = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    tslib_1.__extends(UDFCompatibleDatafeed, _super);
    function UDFCompatibleDatafeed(datafeedURL, intradayFeedUrl, realTimeFeedUrl, enableLogging) {
        var _this = this;
        var requester = new Requester();
        var quotesProvider = new QuotesProvider(datafeedURL, requester);
        _this = _super.call(this, datafeedURL, intradayFeedUrl, realTimeFeedUrl, quotesProvider, requester, enableLogging) || this;
        return _this;
    }
    return UDFCompatibleDatafeed;
})(UDFCompatibleDatafeedBase);
export default UDFCompatibleDatafeed;
```

Then inside my **TVChartContainer.jsx** file

```js
 const UDFCompatibleDatafeed = await import("./datafeeds/udf/src/udf-compatible-datafeed.js");
        console.log("UDFCompatibleDatafeed", UDFCompatibleDatafeed);
 console.log("3...");

       

        const widgetOptions = {
            //debug: true,
            symbol: this.props.symbol,
            // BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
            datafeed: new UDFCompatibleDatafeed(
                this.props.datafeedUrl,
                this.props.intradayUrl,
                this.props.realTimeUrl,
                this.props.enableLogging
            ),
            interval: this.props.interval,
           
        };
```

This is my console logout put

[image]

And I am getting an error

> TypeError: UDFCompatibleDatafeed is not a constructor

**How do we identify whether this is a valid JS class or not?**

Answer (score 0):

I think just removing `new` will do the trick. you are returning a function, not a class.

```
datafeed: UDFCompatibleDatafeed(...)
```